# os.path.basename works with URLs, why?

Tags: python, url, path

```
>>> os.path.basename('http://example.com/file.txt')
'file.txt'
```

.. and I thought `os.path.*` work only on local paths and not URLs? Note that the above example was run on Windows too .. with similar result.

Comment: Clarification: I am not asking about /why/ it works (for which the source code is obviously way to go); rather I am asking why should it work at all (by policy - especially on Windows '\' is path separator)

Comment: Microsoft OSes accept `/` forward slash as a path separator from `Dos 2`, although from `Dos 3` using `/` was disabled by the command shell (it is not any more) because it was conflicting with command line option flag notation. Because of that many implementation is simply not aware of the validity of `/`. Python apparently is. Also, you cannot use forward slashes with the `"\\?\"` prefix. sources http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#paths

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In practice many functions of `os.path` are just string manipulation functions (which just *happen* to be especially handy for path manipulation) -- and since that's innocuous and occasionally handy, while formally speaking "incorrect", I doubt this will change anytime soon -- for more details, use the following simple one-liner at a shell/command prompt:

```
$ python -c"import sys; import StringIO; x = StringIO.StringIO(); sys.stdout = x; import this; sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__; print x.getvalue().splitlines()[10][9:]"
```

Or, for Python 3:

```
$ python -c"import sys; import io; x = io.StringIO(); sys.stdout = x; import this; sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__; print(x.getvalue().splitlines()[10][9:])"
```

Comment: I have to say the one-liner is very impressive.

Comment: @ars, tx, " is indeed better AND cross-platform so I edited. @sunqiang, glad you liked it!-)

Comment: Heh. Anyways, it seems to me that using `os.path.basename` (or split, or whatnot) in this maner (by passing URL) is evil .. as this is not a documented behavior (and might change in future).

Comment: @srid, yep -- theurl.rsplit('/',1)[1] is definitely a better, safer approach.

Comment: Not to forget the query and anchor part in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, look at the source code: C:\Python25\Lib\ntpath.py

```
def basename(p):
    """Returns the final component of a pathname"""
    return split(p)[1]
```

os.path.split (in the same file) just split "\" (and sth. else)

Comment: is using `os.path.basename` on URLs the pythonic way to extract this kind of information from them? or should I use `urlpare.urparse('<myurl>').path` instead?

Comment: @naxa sorry for the delay response, I can't say it's pythonic, thought It look go's path/filepath.Base "support" url too. I kind of prefer urlparse for url handle.

Answer (score 3):

Beware of URLs with parameters, anchors or anything that isn't a "plain" URL:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename("protocol://fully.qualifie.host/path/to/file.txt")
'file.txt'
>>> os.path.basename("protocol://fully.qualifie.host/path/to/file.txt?param1&param1#anchor")
'file.txt?param1&param1#anchor'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the source Luke:

```
def basename(p):
    """Returns the final component of a pathname"""
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    return p[i:]
```

**Edit (response to clarification):**

It works for URLs by accident, that's it. Because of that, exploiting its behaviour could be considered code smell by some.

Trying to "fix" it (check if passed path is not url) is also surprisingly difficult

```
www.google.com/test.php
me@other.place.com/12
./src/bin/doc/goto.c
```

are at the same time correct pathnames and URLs (relative), so is the `http:/hello.txt` (one /, and only on linux, and it's kinda stupid :)). You could "fix" it for absolute urls but relative ones will still work. Handling one special case in differently is a big no no in the python world.

To sum it up: **import this**

Comment: "To sum it up: import this" - what does that mean? I don't see what it does and what it would achieve in the context of the question

Answer (score 1):

Forward slash is also an acceptable path delimiter in Windows.

It is merely that the command line does not accept paths that begin with a / because that character is reserved for args switches.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because it's useful for parsing URLs as well as local file paths. Why not?

Comment: Because it's in the os.path module, and that isn't a path as understood by the OS if you're running windows; the path seperator is different. I believe that / is a valid filename character in Windows, which would make a URL a valid falename, and this behaviour incorrect. I'm not a Windows user, so some, or all of, this comment might be gibberish.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, Microsoft's implementation of the C library actually lets you use / as a valid alternative to \ (the OS itself, at syscall/Win32API levels, did up to a point, but I think it doesn't since a few years ago;-).

Comment: @Alex Martelli, If that's still true, then that would make sense.