# Beautiful Soup and URL base names in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, radix

How would you use Beautiful soup to get a URL base name in python? Given the url name as a string, what would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use urlparse over BeautifulSoup for extracting pieces of a URL.  Here's an example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

parsedurl = urlparse('http://example.com/filename.txt')
print parsedurl.path
```

The output will be:

/filename.txt

Answer (score 3):

If by base name you mean, given `http://example.com/file.txt` you want `file.txt`? In that case you do not need Beautiful Soup at all. Simple string manipulation code would work.

It is also [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112545/os-path-basename-works-with-urls-why) that `os.path.basename('http://example.com/file.txt)` would give you `file.txt`